# QGIS raster calculator ^2 operation gives negativs results

Tags: qgis, digital-image-processing

I want to compare 2 same tiles at different dates.

I use the raster calculator like this :

```
(IR_band_frb - IR_band-aug)^2
```

But I get this result : 
[image: squared diff between 2 images]

The data range goes from -6049 to 4486 ... Why I get negativ results ?

(Same when I write "abs" instead of "^2" symbol)

I tried

```
sqrt((im1-im2)**2)
```

But I get missing values (transparent "colors" in the output raster). So negatives values are passed to the square root operation.

Maybe do you have a better way for comparing 2 rasters in QGIS, do not hesitate !

Ty !

Comment: It may be that the squared numbers are too large, and they exceed the storage capacity of your raster format.

Comment: But when I apply sqrt((im1-im2)^2), I get missing values resulting transparent "color" in the output raster. That indicates some negatives values are passed to the root squared operation.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you square the difference between the images anyway?

If you just do (Raster_1 - Raster_2) as the equation then any values you get that are negative mean that Raster_2 > than Raster_1 whereas positive values show that Raster_1 > Raster_2.

Would this information not be helpful?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/168454)

Comment: @whyzar I believe this answer addresses the part of the question where they asked for "a better way for comparing 2 rasters in QGIS."

Comment: I wantt to have a positiv difference because I dont care if image 1 > image 2 or vice versa. I just want to measure "the difference" between them and then apply a threshold to keep only the constant structures